# Magento 2 Custom Tab Pass Variable Value To The Title

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.2.6

I created a custom tab and set it up by using layout instruction

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="custom.prod.tab2" template="MyComp_Mymod::customtab2.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
            <arguments>
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">More Info</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

The title of the tab needs to be value of a dropdown in the backend (dropdown attribute with multiple options) e.g. on product A the tab title could be ABC and on product B it could be XYZ whatever is selected in the backend.

Is there a way to pass on the selected dropdown value in the configuration here either through XML or via a variable through PHTML template ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like that:

```
 <argument name="value" xsi:type="helper" helper="Vendor\module\Helper\Data::dev"/>
```

create this method `dev` and get current product object inside this method and return to that attribute value.